# Create vim function that reads a single key

Tags: vim, dictionary, macros

How can I make a vim function wait for a single key press?

Example:

- create a function NextOccur that is mapped to execute when key `f` is pressed
- when `f` is pressed nothing should help right away
- after the next key (let's say `x`) is pressed, the cursor should move to the next ocurrence of `x`

> PS: Yes, I know that's exactly what `f` does by default (although its only linewise), but I was wondering if WE could implement functionality like this, ourselves

What if I want to wait for the next two keypresses, is that also possible?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/15.html)?

Comment: @romainl Very nice, reading it from the start, but, still, having trouble mapping keys together with :execute command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built-in `getchar()` function. It waits for a single keypress and then returns it. For an ordinary 8-bit character, you have to use `nr2char(getchar())` to convert it to a String.

It seems you want to extend the `f` / `t` commands to cover multiple lines, too. Be aware that there are already plugins that do that, for example [ft_improved](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3877).

Comment: Nice. 
So, for instance 

`:execute "normal /" . nr2char(getchar()) . nr2char(getchar()) . "\<cr>"` waits for two keys and jump to the next occurence of it.

And maybe this is a differently question entirely but how come the following code doesn't work?

`:map f :execute "normal /" . nr2char(getchar()) . nr2char(getchar()) . "\<cr>"<cr>`

Comment: Escaping: `"\<cr>"` needs to be `"\<lt>cr>"`

Comment: Perfect. Althought it's kind of ugly, the following works for me: `:nnoremap <silent> f :execute ("normal /" . nr2char(getchar()) . nr2char(getchar
()) . "\<lt>cr>") <cr>`. (well and it feels strange that `"\<cr>"` worked in the first case, but not when mapping a key)